# Custom Post Type - Admin Columns

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, tags, contextual-help

I'm getting these 0's in front of my categories and tags:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7v9hvf25wsw15p8/Screenshot%202014-11-08%2020.50.02.png?dl=0

Here's what the code in function looks like:

```
// Work columns
function work_edit_columns($columns){
   $columns = array(
                    "cb" => "<input type='checkbox' />",
                    "title" => __("Work"),
                    "work_category" => __("Category"),
                                        "work_hashtags" => __("Tags"),
                    "date" => __("Date")
                   );

   return $columns;
}


add_action("manage_work_posts_custom_column",  "work_custom_columns");

function work_custom_columns($column){
  global $post;
  switch ($column){
                 case "work_category":
                     echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'work_category', '', ', ','');
                 break;
   }

   global $post;
   switch ($column){
                  case "work_hashtags":
                      echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'work_hashtag', '', ', ','');
                  break;
     }
 }
```

Is there any way to remove this?

Comment: Try disabling javascript and check what happen? Also you can try disabling Plugins one by one if any of them causes the issue. Check whether you have any typo there... :)

Comment: Ah, 'Like This' Plugin was causing the 0's problem! :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting the '0's.  But you shouldn't be using 2 switch statements in work_custom_columns().

Try this:

```
function work_custom_columns($column){
  global $post;
  switch ($column){
                 case "work_category":
                     echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'work_category', '', ', ','');
                 break;

                  case "work_hashtags":
                      echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'work_hashtag', '', ', ','');
                  break;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for that one @shanebp - I figured out the problem with the '0's, and it was caused by a plugin called 'Like This'.